# Migrate custom directives with the attributes "link" and "priority" from AngularJS to Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, upgrade, custom-directive

I'm trying to migrate a project from AngularJS 1.5.8 to a recent version of Angular (latest stable, hopefully). I'm following the official upgrade guide (https://angular.io/guide/upgrade). Right now I'm stuck in the conversion to component directives (https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-component-directives). It is unclear to me how custom directives are supposed to be migrated, but I assumed they should also be converted to component directives, like controllers/templates pairs do.

My project has custom directives, and many of them make use of the attributes "link" and "priority".

How would you convert a custom directive into a component directive (or do the migration any other way for that matter), if:

Issue 1) According to the guide, component directives should not use the "priority" attribute.

Issue 2) Your custom directive uses this "link" attribute, which does not exist in a component directive.

Thanks in advance